# Stop-AzureWebsite -Name <sitename> does not work

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to stop a azure website to make some changes to it but the power-shell does not do it anymore. Was using this method for months now

the command just hangs and after a while I get A task was canceled exception

Anyone had the same?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic: Per one of the answers: this is a transient issue related to a service outage. There's no solution (other than waiting for the issue to be rectified).

Answer (score 1):

There is a current outage. I'm having similar issue. I cannot manage some cloud services on Azure portal. And my PowerShell deployment script timed out.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#current

"An alert for Microsoft Azure Portal in Multiple Regions is currently being investigated. More information will be provided as it is known."

Answer (score 0):

Havnt experienced that but if it is of much urgency you can stop the site from the azure portal under App Services.

Comment: I know that that is a workaround but I want my power-shell to work :). Putted that to MS support to see what they can come up with. Will post here after

Comment: That will be great, powershell makes work faster :-)

Comment: @Jester - you should unmark this as accepted answer, since your issue is related to a transient service outage (and the question itself should be deleted).